# Problem when trying to create a RDS database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

When I try to click on 'Create Database', the following message appears to me.

Cannot find major version 5.7 for oscar

[image: error]

Comment: If I refresh the page 3 or 4 times, the creation page opens.

Comment: It sounds like a browser code issue. Try it in a different browser, or perhaps do a shift-refresh. FYI, you can lodge product Feedback to AWS via the **Feedback** button in the bottom-left corner.

Comment: I had this happen also and shift+command+R (on a Mac) seemed to resolve it.